# Generated json object retuning number as string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, methods

I have this vue method that takes input vales from user and generates a json object before it performs the axios put request. My issue is that the json object generated is returning numbers as strings, and that breaks my API response. My goal is for my json object to be like this:

```
{
  "test":{
    "test1":{
      "test2":2,
      "test3": 2
    }
  }
}
```

On current code, json object returns like this (2 as string):

```
{
  "test":{
    "test1":{
      "test2":"2",
      "test3":"2"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my vue method:

```
generateJson() {
  const values = {}

  this.inputs.forEach((item) => {
    values[item.key] = item.value
  })

  const jsonFile = {
    test: {
      test1: values
    }
  }

    const testUrl = '*URL placeholder*'

    axios.put(testUrl, jsonFile).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }
}
```

This is the user input field:

```
    <button @click.prevent="showInput">+</button>
    <div v-for="(input, k) in inputs" :key="k">
        <input v-model="input.key" type="text" @change="getKey($event)" />
        <input
              v-model="input.value"
              type="text"
              @change="getValue($event)"
            />
    </div>

</div>
<button @click.prevent="generateJson">Submit</button>
```

And here is the other two methods that i use to get the value from input:

```
data() {
  return {
    tempkey: '',
    tempValue: '',
  }
}
getKey(e) {
  this.tempkey = e.target.value
},
getValue(e) {
  this.tempValue = e.target.value
},
```

Anyone can advise what i can do to make this work? Many thanks.

Comment: What is `this.inputs`? A list of HTML `<input>`? Then what is `item.key`? Obviously `item.value` does return a string. If you *know*  it's a number you can simply do `values[item.key] = +item.value` If there are inputs of different types, you have to check beforehand, but as we don't know, what `item` really is, it's hard to advise.

Comment: @derpirscher thanks, i just added the remaining part of my code. Also, i did added the + in from of item.value and that work. Can you share why that is the case?

Comment: the plain `value` of an HTML `<input>` element is always a string, regardless of what you set `type=...`. Thus when you try to fetch the value from this element, you always get a string. The [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)  tries to convert this string to a number. I don't have any experience with vue.js, but there is probably a way to define the model accordingly, so that the framework does this conversion automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs of type 'text' will return a string. Try changing the input type to number.
Otherwise, you could do this (with type text):

```
getKey(e) {
 this.tempkey = parseInt(e.target.value)
}
getValue(e) {
 this.tempValue = parseInt(e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: In plain js, the `value` of an [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) is *always* a string, regardless of what you set the `type='...'` to. If you want it converted to a number you can either convert it to a number with `parseInt/Float`, or use the unary +,  or use `input.valueAsNumber`